# How to select range of cells with value in a column, I don't want to select empty cells so that when I create a bar graph it won't have 0s in it

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code I have with me now, line 6 isn't working as intended. I am already able to create the graph, it just has 0s in it. I want it to be fully coded meaning I don't want to manually select the 0s by filtering the data set or replacing the 0s with NAs unless I can do that via VBA. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Summary")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs")

Set MyRange = Range(ws1.Range("X1:"), ws1.Range("X2").End(xlDown).Row).Select

'Range("A1:I" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Select

Set MyRange2 = ws1.Range("Y:Y")

Dim MyChart As ChartObject
Set MyChart = ws2.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=260, Left:=815, Width:=400, Height:=250)

With MyChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted
    .DisplayValueNotAvailableAsBlank = False
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Test"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = MyRange
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = MyRange2
    .SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
    .HasLegend = False
End With
```

This is my initial code to create the graph, I only selected 4 values, I want to be able to select the columns and filter out the empty values or select until the last cell that has value.

```
With chart3.Chart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted
    .DisplayValueNotAvailableAsBlank = False
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Test"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws1.Range("X2:X5")
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws1.Range("Y2:Y5")
    .SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
    .HasLegend = False
End With
```

Comment: Try `Set MyRange = Range(ws1.Range("X1:"), ws1.Range("X2").End(xlDown).Row):  MyRange.Select`

Comment: Are the zeros at the bottom of your data or are they everywhere?

Comment: Create two arrays from the Ranges without 0 values and set them to the properties `XValues`, and `Values`

Comment: Generally zero at the bottom because it will be empty and the first cell, X1 & Y1 wont be selected, it will be best if i can select cell from X2 & Y2 until the last cell that contains values @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

- You can't use `Select` method in `Set` clause.

```
Set MyRange = Range(ws1.Range("X1:"), ws1.Range("X2").End(xlDown).Row).Select
```

- It should be as below.

```
Set MyRange = ws1.Range("X1", ws1.Range("X2").End(xlDown))
MyRange.Select
```

***Note:*** You don't need `select` in most cases. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

---

- Get the last row# with `End(xlUp).Row`

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
With chart3.Chart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted
    .DisplayValueNotAvailableAsBlank = False
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Test"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws1.Range("X2:X" & lastRow)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & lastRow)
    .SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
    .HasLegend = False
End With
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help do you know whether I can use xldown instead to the last cell with value? Cause I am not able to get the desired one with your code. I tried using the xldown but it will continue selecting all the 0 value.

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question w/o knowing your data.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No worries thanks for the help but my data I am trying to select is column X row 2 till the last row cell with value, same with column Y

Comment: `xlDown` works well on your data.

Comment: But for some reasons it keeps on selecting all the empty data as well, it does not stop at the last row cell with value

Comment: Are there any formulas on the empty data cell?

Comment: I would assume there isn't but X2 have this formula:
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(H2:H100,H2:H100<>"")))
But when I run my initial code I am able to get value from the cell for X2, X3 and X4

Answer (score 0):

### Find the Last Non-Blank Cell Using the Find Method

- When you want to exclude blank cells that are not empty at the bottom of your data, you can use the `Find` method with its 3rd argument (`LookIn`) set to `xlValues`.
- `UsedRange`, `CurrentRegion`, `End`, and `Find` with `xlFormulas` won't work.

```vb
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range, MyRange2 As Range, lcell As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Summary")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs")

With ws1.Range("X2")
    Set lcell = .Resize(ws1.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If lcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data found
    Set MyRange = .Resize(lcell.Row - .Row + 1)
End With

Set MyRange2 = MyRange.EntireRow.Columns("Y")

' Continue with the chart code...
```